# MYSQL: automatically extract the YEAR from the date input into another column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a dateOfBirth column and a yearOfBirth column. The input only contains the DOB information. What I am looking for is to just insert DOB info into the db, and the mysql will auto update the year column field with the year extracted from the date inserted. Is it possible to be done?

Right now my MySQL query is just

```
INSERT INTO table
    (name, dateOfBirth, yearOfBirth) 
    VALUES (?)
```

How should I change that?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Nick vversion 8

Answer (score 1):

It is *possible* to do this using a trigger, but I don't see any practical reason to do it.  Instead, just leverage the `YEAR()` function if you want to present the year in a query:

```
SELECT
    name,
    dateOfBirth,
    YEAR(dateOfBirth) AS yearOfBirth
FROM yourTable;
```

Storing the birthdates in a bona fide date column is the best design choice, and any derivative of that can be had using a function or cast.

**Edit:**

If your reason for wanting to do this is adding an index by year, you can instead just add an index on the `dateOfBirth` field:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (dateOfBirth)
```

If you wanted to query for a certain year, say 2018, you could try the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE dateOfBirth >= '2018-01-01' AND dateOfBirth < '2019-01-01';
```

This in fact would be sargable, meaning that the index we created above could be used.

Comment: The problem is I need to extract the year out into another column and index on the year column. Cant think of any other way to do that.

Comment: I can.  Just index the date field itself.

Comment: MySQL 8 can generate an index based on a function of the data: `CREATE TABLE t1 (col1 INT, col2 INT, INDEX func_index ((ABS(col1))));` (see the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html))

Comment: @nimrodm What is the point of using a function index here when the original date column itself is probably sufficient?

Comment: I edited your answer as the Index has to be on dateOfBirth column, since your solution also does not recommend creating yearofbirth field

Comment: That was a typo...I wasn't paying attention.  Your assumption is correct.

Comment: But wouldn't indexing based on date of birth be slow for insertion and updating? That means every insertion of a different DOB would create new index and this adds so much overhead rather than just indexing based on yearOfBirth (since the uniqueness of DOB is more common than YOB).

Comment: Not true at all.  First of all, inserting a new record and updating a B-tree is less costly than you might think, and MySQL has all sorts of tricks to make this fast (most of the time).  Second, the size of a potential index using the full birthdate or just the year would be about the same size, assuming it covers the same columns.  There isn't much argument for maintaining a separate year column here.